# Magento 2 Email not receiving after order

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, email

Magento order emails not receiving, is that any particular setting in default magento 2?

Comment: no, not a single email received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if cron is scheduled on you server and if it is not, then you need to set it by following.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/Your_Project/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/Your_Project/var/log/magent$
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/Your_Project/update/cron.php >> /var/www/Your_Project/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/Your_Project/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/Your_Project/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Note: You need to set location of your project in scheduling

If you still not getting emails then you need to use 3rd party emails services, and to do this you will be needing SMTP module like:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageaurigait-smtpmailer.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/yogeshkhasturi-anysmtp.html

You can use one of these

Hope you find your answer :)